# Segfault accessing shared memory in Python

Tags: python, shared-memory

I've been getting a segfault when trying to access shared memory, which I've boiled down to the following example. `f1` and `f2` are identical save for the fact that I'm storing the shared memory object in an extra variable in `f2`, but `f2` works and `f1` segfaults. Why would this happen?

(Calling the two functions in the opposite order does not change the behavior.)

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import numpy as np

segment_name = "segment"
data_shape = (5,5,5)


def get_view(shm):
    shape = (1,) + data_shape
    arr_one = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=np.float64, buffer=shm.buf)
    arr_two = np.ndarray(data_shape, dtype=np.float64, buffer=arr_one[0])
    return arr_two


def f1():
    arr = get_view(shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=segment_name))
    print(arr[0][0][0])


def f2():
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=segment_name)
    arr = get_view(shm)
    print(arr[0][0][0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    shape = (1,) + data_shape
    dummy = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=np.float64)
    shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=segment_name, create=True, size=dummy.nbytes)
    f2()
    f1()
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the extra reference was necessary. Without `arr` pointing to the shared memory object, its `del` method would be invoked immediately and unlink the underlying buffer whose reference was held by the numpy array.